# Java 8 - Recursive delete of folders according to predicate

Tags: java, java-8, functional-programming, java-stream

The requirement is to traverse a series of folders to identify and delete subfolders (at any level) and their content based on a folder name pattern. I have working code using Java 7's visitor class but now trying to make it work with Java 8 streams.

I came up with some working code (see below) but it's my impression that it should exist a better, simpler way of doing the same without repeating myself.

```
  public void delete(List<Path> folders) {
     folders
     .stream()
     .filter(Files::isDirectory)
     .forEach(this::evaluateIfTrash);
  }

  private void evaluateIfTrash(Path folder) {
    try (Stream<Path> dir = Files.walk(folder, FileVisitOption.FOLLOW_LINKS)) {
      dir.filter(Files::isDirectory)
          .filter(TrashPredicate::isTrashFolder)
          .forEach(this::recursivelyDelete);
    } catch (IOException e) {
      log.error("Failed to evaluate {}", folder, e);
    }
  }

  private void recursivelyDelete(Path folder) {
    try (Stream<Path> dir = Files.walk(folder, FileVisitOption.FOLLOW_LINKS)) {
      dir.sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder())
          .map(Path::toFile)
          .filter(File::exists)
          .forEach(File::delete);
    } catch (IOException e) {
      log.error("Failed to delete {}", folder, e);
    }
  }
```

After reading some documentation and several answers here, I tried nested streams as a way to get rid of some duplication:

```
 private void delete(List<Path> folders) {
    folders
    .stream()
    .filter(Files::isDirectory)
    .flatMap(
        f -> {
          try {
            return Files.walk(f, FileVisitOption.FOLLOW_LINKS);
          } catch (IOException e) {
            return Stream.empty();
          }
        })
    .filter(TrashPredicate::isTrashFolder)
    .forEach(this::recursivelyDelete);
  }

private void recursivelyDelete(Path folder) {
    try (Stream<Path> dir = Files.walk(folder, FileVisitOption.FOLLOW_LINKS)) {
      dir.sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder())
          .map(Path::toFile)
          .filter(File::exists)
          .forEach(File::delete);
    } catch (IOException e) {
      log.error("Failed to delete {}", folder, e);
    }
  }
```

This eliminates one of the methods (even if the readability is not as good) but what I really do not like is the fact of not closing the inner stream returned by the flatMap operation. When I try to do it (by using a try-with-resources construct and moving the filter and forEach operation inside the try) I receive an error saying the stream is already closed and not available for further operations.

I've been trying to make this work for the last two days without success, so the question, again, is there a better (cleaner) way of doing this using Java 8?

Comment: I think this is a better candidate for [codereview.se].

Comment: One thing that makes a FileVisitor superior is that it won’t require you to suppress IOExceptions.  Another is that you won’t have to use the obsolete methods of java.io.File, which give no indication of failure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Files.walk will already stream a root path recursively depth first. FileUtils from apache commons has a deleteDirectory which removes directories recursively, making the code also quite clean.

So something like below should work

```
        Files.walk(rootPath)
            .filter(Files::isDirectory).
            .filter(TrashPredicate::isTrashFolder)
            .forEach(FileUtils::deleteDirectory);
```

Comment: Looks nice indeed. The only lacking? thing is that the method receives a list of paths that should be handled and there is no common root path for them.

Comment: You can append Files.walk(path1) , Files.walk(path2) ... streams or merge and flatmap them. Rest is the same